# Generating Separate Datagrids populated by API

Tags: wpf, api, dynamic, datagrid

Hey so I'm having an issue of finding a way how to generate a datagrid (with only 1 markup for it . i.e. I want to have only 1  tag and from there to be able to populate the window with separate datagrids from an API. Is that even possible to dynamically generate separate datagrids?
Please help  , so far I could only hardcode it (as in have separate datagrids for separate a API connections and displaying that data)

```
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
                <DataGrid Margin="0,214,0,222">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Currency" Width="150"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Balance" Width="150"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Available" Width="150"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pending" Width="150"/>

                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
                <DataGrid Margin="0,421,0,10">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Currency" Width="150"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Balance" Width="150"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Available" Width="150"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pending" Width="150"/>

                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Comment: In the same way that you can have a `DataTemplate` within a `Datatemplate`, perhaps you could create a `DataTemplate` that contains a `Datagrid`?

Comment: Any clue how that will work? Like can you refer an example?

Comment: Assuming that you are retrieving a list of similar objects, each of which containing their own lists of objects, I don't see why you couldn't create a `Datagrid` datatemplate and assign the `ItemsSource` as your API return. If you are unfamiliar with the concepts of `ItemsControl` and `DataTemplate` I would recommend searching those terms.

Comment: [This may be what you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161157/binding-datagrid-within-a-datatemplate-of-itemscontrol)

Answer (score 0):

Create an `ObservableCollection` of objects, each of which representing a DataGrid `ItemsSource`. Perhaps by returning the API calls to the collection.

Bind that collection to an `ItemsControl` and create a `DataTemplate` containing your `Datagrid` definition.

Create the Columns and assign the `Datagrid.ItemsSource` to the bound object, bind the columns to the properties of the bound object.